# How much accessing msg.sender costs? Is it useful to store it in a variable and then use it instead of accessing msg.sender multiple times?

Tags: solidity

How much accessing msg.sender costs? Is it useful to store it in a variable and then use it instead of accessing msg.sender multiple times? I have to access current user variable multiple times in a function.

Answer (score 3):

Using msg.sender will always be cheaper than using a local variable.

The reason is the following:

The `CALLER` operation which is reading the `msg.sender` global variable costs 2.

While `MLOAD/MSTORE` operations which are memory operations (storage where local variables are stored) costs 3.

You can check gas costs for each operation [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0).